# Icon theme does not work with default theme?

Tags: flutter

It seems icon theme does not work for card with default theme.

```
theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.red, // this does not work, it renders in grey color
    ),
),
darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.red, // it is OK
    ),
),
```

there is a card

```
Card(
    child: ListTile(
       trailing: const Icon(Icons.brightness_4)), // renders in grey
    ),
),
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use icon color in ListTile trailing property having a light theme.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            selected: true,
            trailing: Icon(Icons.brightness_4),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```